# Compana function for compositional analysis freezes in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run compositional analysis of the use of different type of habitats by ground nesting chicks on a set of data using R Studio. It starts processing but gives never stops. I have to manually stop the processing or kill R Studio. (Same result in R.)

I'm using the campana function from the adehabitatHS package. From the adehabitat I'm able to run the sample pheasant and squirrel data without any problems. (I've tried calling campana from both packages with the same result.)

For each chick, the habitat available varies as it's taken as a buffer zone around their nest site.

My data
This is the available habitats for each chick:

```
grass fallow.plot oil.seed.rape spring.barley winter.wheat maize other.crops other woodland hedgerow
1  23.35        7.53         45.75          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00  0.00    23.37     0.00
2  86.52       10.35          0.00          0.00         1.24  0.00        0.00  1.89     0.00     0.00
3   5.18       10.33         28.36         38.82         0.00  0.00       17.17  0.14     0.00     0.00
4   4.26       18.32         27.31         32.66         3.82  0.00        0.00  5.02     5.52     3.09
5   4.26       18.32         27.31         32.66         3.82  0.00        0.00  5.02     5.52     3.09
6  12.52       10.35          0.00          0.00         0.00 18.02       43.59 13.15     2.37     0.00
7  21.41       11.56         59.25          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00  5.82     0.00     1.96
8  21.41       11.56         59.25          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00  5.82     0.00     1.96
9  36.17       16.93          0.00         30.14         0.00  0.00        0.00  7.08     9.68     0.00
10  0.00       12.17         26.49          0.00         3.99 55.77        0.00  1.58     0.00     0.00
11  0.00       10.27         67.41          1.93        18.30  0.00        0.00  1.18     0.00     0.91
12  2.66        5.38          0.00         14.39        54.06  0.00        8.40  3.83     7.84     3.44
13  2.66        5.38          0.00         14.39        54.06  0.00        8.40  3.83     7.84     3.44
14 84.22        8.00          0.00          0.00         0.00  2.90        0.00  0.22     3.84     0.82
15 84.22        8.00          0.00          0.00         0.00  2.90        0.00  0.22     3.84     0.82
16 86.85       13.04          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00  0.11     0.00     0.00
17 86.85       13.04          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00  0.11     0.00     0.00
18 86.85       13.04          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00  0.11     0.00     0.00
19 86.85       13.04          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00  0.11     0.00     0.00
20 21.41        8.11          0.47          8.08         0.00  0.00       56.78  2.26     0.00     2.89
```

This is the used habitats (mcp):

```
grass fallow.plot oil.seed.rape spring.barley winter.wheat maize other.crops  other woodland hedgerow
1  41.14       58.67          0.19          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.00        0      0.0
2  35.45       64.55          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.00        0      0.0
3  10.10       60.04          7.72         21.37         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.77        0      0.0
4   0.00       44.55          0.00         50.27         0.00  0.00        0.00   5.18        0      0.0
5   2.82       48.48         44.80          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.00        0      3.9
6   0.00        0.00          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00 100.00        0      0.0
7   0.00       87.41         12.59          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.00        0      0.0
8   0.00       83.59         16.41          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.00        0      0.0
9   0.00      100.00          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.00        0      0.0
10  0.00       18.93          0.00          0.00         0.00 81.07        0.00   0.00        0      0.0
11  0.00      100.00          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.00        0      0.0
12  0.00       22.79          0.00          0.00        77.13  0.00        0.00   0.08        0      0.0
13  0.00        0.00          0.00          0.00       100.00  0.00        0.00   0.00        0      0.0
14 54.60       44.97          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.43        0      0.0
15 62.86       36.57          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.57        0      0.0
16 11.15       88.10          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.75        0      0.0
17 20.06       79.62          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.32        0      0.0
18 38.64       60.95          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.41        0      0.0
19  3.81       95.81          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00        0.00   0.38        0      0.0
20  0.00        3.56          0.00          0.00         0.00  0.00       96.44   0.00        0      0.0
```

I've tried both parametric and randomisation tests with the same results. The code I'm running:

```
habuse <- compana(used, avail, test = "randomisation",rnv = 0.001, nrep = 500, alpha = 0.1)
habuse <- compana(used, avail, test = "parametric")
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the answer to my own question. For the used data, the function replaces 0 values with the value you specify (0.001 in my case). But it doesn't replace 0 values in the available data, and it doesn't like them either.

I replaced all the 0s with 0.001 in the available table, adjusted the other values and the function worked.